# OnTextChanged Event not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, event-handling, html-helper

I have a textbox and I want a JavaScript to run each time the user changes the text of the textbox.

So I used an ontextChanged as follows

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OuterCaseWSP, new
{
      @style = "max-width:145px;",
      @disabled = "disabled", 
      OnTextChanged = "calculateOuterCasePOR()"
})
```

However this does not seem to work.

NOTE: When I replace the OntextChanged with onBlur the code triggers.

What is wrong with the event handler I called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` does not have a `textChanged` event. There is a `change` though, but it will be triggered only when text bpx is blurred, so it is not of a value fo you. However you might want to use `onKeyPress` instead:

```
onKeyPress = "calculateOuterCasePOR()"
```

Comment: Or if you wanted the onChange event as well if onkeypress didn't satisfy you.